Post-apocalyptic movie where a traveler encounters a dying robot displaying images on its face in an old store
I'm looking for an old post-apocalyptic movie where a traveler stops by an old store. There's a robot about to die, and it shows the person pictures on its face before dying.

In roughly which year did you watch this? And can you tell us anything more about it? Was the 'traveler' male or female, for example?

That sounds like a scene from Love and Monsters (2020). The story is set post apocalypse, where cold blooded animals and insects mutated to tremendous size.  There is a scene where the main character finds a barely functional robot called Mav1s in a ruined building that uses the last of its power to show him images from the old internet and to make a radio call to his love interest. Mav1s's face is its display screen.




The OP describes it as "an old post-apocalyptic movie". If 2020 is old, then what are we?

@Randal'Thor I had a similar thought. 2020 was basically yesterday.
